# VB6 find & replace

Tags: vb6

I have a textbox where 'c' code is written which, i want to replace by programmatically

Here goes, 'C' code in multline textbox

```
   for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ; 

   if ( n >= 1
```

with

```
   for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ) ; 

   if ( n >= 1 )
```

where n>=1 or count=2;count<=n may change

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop through the lines of text in the text box. You can do this with the following.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim trimmedLine As String
    Dim i As Integer

    If Len(Text1.Text) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    lines = Split(Text1.Text, vbCrLf)

    For i = 0 To UBound(lines)
        'Trim white space from left of the line. Only used for checking if the line starts with for or if.
        trimmedLine = LTrim(lines(i))

        If StrComp(Left(trimmedLine, 3), "for", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            lines(i) = Left(lines(i), Len(lines(i)) - 1) & ");"
        ElseIf StrComp(Left(trimmedLine, 2), "if", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            lines(i) = lines(i) & ")"
        End If
    Next i

    Text1.Text = Join(lines, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

What you do in the loop to modify the text of each line will depend on your needs. You can use string functions like Replace(), Left(), Right(), Mid(), etc.

That should give you a start.

Comment: Thankyou. It worked for "for"
after clicking on button, " ) " is added only in for loop, but not in "if" condition can you please tell me option

Comment: As mentioned, the actually parsing of each line would depend on the actual text. The example I gave was a simple one. I suspect you have a line with "   if ( n>= 1" so the example I gave wouldn't find "if" at the start of that line. If that's the case you could use line = LTrim(line) to remove the white space from the left of the string before the If/ElseIf. Inside of the If and ElseIf you could then modify lines(i) instead of line. You would just just use line to do the check to see if the line starts with "for" or "if".

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible fix

Comment: What have you tried? Most of what you need is already there. I'm not going to just write it all for you. If you don't understand the string manipulation functions that are used you will need to keep asking for changes each time there's a slight difference in the lines of code that are being parsed.